# Prog. created UIWebView gets on top all other elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm creating a UIWebView programmatically and giving it full width and height, but it puts itself on top of all other elements. I've got a couple of buttons and a UIActivityIndicatorView that I want to be on top of that UIWebView.

How do I change the "layering" programmatically? On IB I can move them on the object list, but this last item it's inserted programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:webView];
```

Answer (score 5):

[self.view insertSubview:WebView atIndex:0];

Try this code and this will made your webb always in the background of the view....

Comment: @Adirael, this answer will work when any other control not having same index(i.e. 0).

Comment: @Ishu Gupta This answer will always work. Inserting a subview at a given index will move forward other subviews as needed.

Comment: @Justin my means is only that after adding this web view.You cant assign 0 index to other if you do that then that view take position at 0 index.